# R How to remove any two consecutive words?

Tags: r, regex

How can I create a function such that one of any two consecutive words (in my case separated by an underscore) is removed without specifying the words?

```r
## Some examples
c("ethnicity_ethnicity_selected_choice",
  "child_1_child_child_pid")
#> [1] "ethnicity_ethnicity_selected_choice" "child_1_child_child_pid"

## Output needed
c("ethnicity_selected_choice",
  "child_1_child_pid")
#> [1] "ethnicity_selected_choice" "child_1_child_pid"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Do you have a list of consecutive words to check for, or are you saying if any two words are identical, you want to keep only one copy? Could there be more than two in a row?

Comment: The latter, and yes there could more than two in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to find:

```
([^_]+)(?:_\1(?=_|$))*
```

Replace with `\1`, see an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uwLkav/1)

---

- `([^_]+)` - A capture group to catch 1+ non-underscore characters;
- `(?:_\1` - An non-capture group matching an underscore and a backreference to the 1st capture group;

  - `(?=_|$)` - A nested positive lookahead with either an underscore *or* end-line anchor;
  - `)*` - Close non-capture group and match 0+ times.

---

```
library(stringr)
v <- c("ethnicity_ethnicity_selected_choice",
  "child_1_child_child_pid")
v <- str_replace_all(v, "([^_]+)(?:_\\1(?=_|$))*", "\\1")
v
```

Prints:

```
"ethnicity_selected_choice", "child_1_child_pid"
```

Comment: Your regex works without the lookahead.

Comment: @its.me.adam, it wouldn't since there is a chance for false positives at the end of a string.

Comment: @JdV But I tried it and it works on `child_child`. May you show an example?

Comment: @its.me.adam, That will work, but I was talking about *false positives*. Here is an [example](https://regex101.com/r/eKZUYn/1).

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```r
s <- c("ethnicity_ethnicity_selected_choice",
  "child_1_child_child_child_pid", "child_1_child_childhood_pid",
  "child_child")

gsub("(?<=_|)(\\w+)(_\\1)+(?=_|$)", "\\1", s, perl = T)

#> [1] "ethnicity_selected_choice"   "child_1_child_pid"          
#> [3] "child_1_child_childhood_pid" "child"
```

Comment: Note that you are not actually replacing *consecutive* values here since you capture 1+ word-characters including underscores. You also don't actually include the underscore in the capture group which can lead to false positives. Like `child_childhood` turns into `childhood`.

Comment: You are right, @JvdV! Thanks for calling my attention to that. Fixed now!

Comment: You are welcome. Not trying to nitpick but now you would leave `child_1_child_child` as is. =). The minute I mentioned this I also realize my solution is also faulty and will return `child_` when dealing with `child_child`.

Comment: Hope now it is fixed, @JvdV! Thanks for your help and feedback!